# Show that the given sequence is convergent in $(C[0,1],\|\|_1 )$ but not in $(C[0,1], \|\|_\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, solution-verification

Let $f_n(x) := x^n$ for $x \in [0, 1]$, for $n \in \mathbb N$ . Show that the sequence $(f_n)$ is convergent in $(C[0, 1],\|\|_1 )$ whereas it is not convergent in $(C[0,1],\|\|_\infty)$.

Here's my attempt on the second part :
Suppose $f_n(x)$ is convergent in $(C[0,1],\|\|_\infty)$ and let its limit point be $g(x)$, So for $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists$  $n_0$ $\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\|f_n - g\|_\infty$ < $\epsilon$ for $n$ $\geq n_0$  i.e $\|x^n - g(x)\|_\infty$ < $\epsilon$ for $n$ $\geq n_0$ or $sup_{(0\leq x\leq1)}|x^n - g(x)|$ $< \epsilon$  for $n$ $\geq n_0$, Now if $(i)$ $g(x) = 1$ for some  $ x\in [0,1]$ then $sup_{(0\leq x\leq1)}|x^n - g(x)|$ $\geq 1$ so by taking $\epsilon = 1/2$ implies that $f_n(x)$ is not convergent.
$(ii)$ $g(x)\ne1$ for $x \in[0,1]$ so $|1-g(t)|>0$ for some $t\in[0,1]$ then  $sup_{(0\leq x\leq1)}|x^n - g(x)|\geq |1-g(t)| $, so by taking $\epsilon = |1-g(x)|/2$ implies that $f_n(x)$ is not convergent, therefore in either case it is not convergent in $(C[0,1], \|\|_\infty)$

Comment: Do you talk about point convergence or uniform convergence?Its way too diferrent..I give you a hint for point convergence you have to see for $x\in [0,1)$ and for x=1 the limit is not the zero function

Comment: It's about uniform convergence

Comment: Notice that $f_n(x)=x^n->0$ only in the case that x is on [0,1).If x=1 then $f_n(x)=1$.If $f_n(x)$ are continuous and $f_n-->f$ uniformly then f should be also continuous function but here the limit is not continuous on x=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f_n \to f$ in $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ then $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ for all $x \in [0,1]$. So there is only one candidate limit if the sequence converges.

The pointwise limit $(f_n)$ is $$f(x)=\begin{cases} 0 & 0 \le x < 1\\
                                                    1 & x=1\end{cases}$$

which is not continuous so is not in $C([0,1])$.

In $\|\cdot \|_1$ the sequence converges to $g(x)\equiv 0, g \in C([0,1])$, as $$\|f_n - g\|_1 = \int_0^1 |f_n(x)-g(x)|\,dx = \int_0^1 x^n dx = \frac{1}{n+1} \to 0$$

Comment: I know this one, how about the other part. I'm updating proof for the latter part you can verify it for me

Comment: @LucasHaobam I did show it is not convergent at the start: suppose $f_n \to f$ for some $f \in C([0,1])$, for convergence in $\|\cdot\|_\infty$, but then $f$ equals the $f$ that I gave above, contradiction. So it does *not* converge.

Comment: Ohh! I didn't see that. Yeah! it works. I'm writing a proof too. will be uploading it once I complete it. Will you please verify it? (I'm new to stackexchange)

Comment: @LucasHaobam The argument you give is way too complicated, just use the pointwise limit argument. Keep it simple.